# Kotlin mutableMap.put returns nullable

Tags: nullable, kotlin

In kotlin standard lib we have `MutableMap` interface
which has this method

```
public abstract fun put(key: K, value: V): V?
```

Why is it returning nullable value if it accepts not nullable one? Is it done for java interop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the definition

```
/**
 * Associates the specified [value] with the specified [key] in the map.
 *
 * @return the previous value associated with the key, or `null` if the key was not present in the map.
 */
public fun put(key: K, value: V): V?
```

So

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var m: MutableMap<Int, String> = mutableMapOf(Pair(1, "a"))
    val prev1Value = m.put(1, "b")
    val prev2Value = m.put(2, "c")

    println(m)
    println("Previous value of 1 was: $prev1Value")
    println("Previous value of 2 was: $prev2Value")
}
```

Prints:

```
{1=b, 2=c}
Previous value of 1 was: a
Previous value of 2 was: null
```

Comment: oh seems intellij was using decompiler all this time... gonna find how to attach sources

Comment: I use IntelliJ Idea 15.0.4. Simply hold `ctrl` and click on `put` function

Comment: Also you can use `ctrl+shift+i` to open quick definition